State after measurement in "Delayed choice for entanglement swapping"
I'm reading this paper below, but it seems to me the conclusions are not correct.
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9904042
Alice and Bob independently prepare the Bell state $\Psi^-$.  They measure one qubit and send the other qubit to Eve.  The joint state of the system is written in terms of the qubit-pair Eve now has on the right side of equation 6 (page 3).
That state, however, is the state assuming Alice and Bob have NOT measured a qubit.  They then deduce probabilities of results if Eve performs Bell measurements on her qubit pair.  It seems to me this is bogus: given that Alice & Bob measured and collapsed the state, how can we subsequently use the state before those measurements?
While writing this I realized the main jist of the paper may still work if we assume Alice/Bob measured "after" Eve, so Eve did measure on the state in equation 6.  Maybe this is just a minor problem with how the concept was introduced?  Or maybe I'm missing something bigger, "after" may be problematic here?

The words "before" and "after" are not useful in a relativistic universe. Which measurement comes first is observer dependent. IMHO pretty much all the confusion about these issues stems from the false assumption that quantum mechanics can be analyzed in an absolute Aritotelian framework. It can't. Quantum mechanics is always fully relativistic, even at low energies.

In general "delayed choice" and FTL communication has been debunked ... see wikipedia for example.  A naive theory is employed in the paper, it ignores the fact that the EM field is always active, works at the speed of light and influences all energy/photon transfer.  Even before the photon is created the excited electron already influences the field (similar in some respects to pilot wave).  This is also true of the DSE .... there's no great mystery.

@FlatterMann Measurement order can be observer dependent in some scenarios, but there are plenty where the order is not ambiguous. Your comment is irrelevant, because in the cited Peres paper: The order of the the quantum observation doesn't matter anyway. And the experiment can be such that the "Eve" measurement is unambiguously before or after the Alice/Bob measurements. See for example figure 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.4834 where there's an extra 104m of coiled fiber. The Victor measurement occurs "after" in all reference frames, regardless of the relative velocity of the observer.

@PhysicsDave Nope, wrong again. Quantum teleportation (Entanglement Swapping), Delayed Choice, Quantum Nonlocality, etc are quite accepted these days. From the 2022 Nobel awards: "...Anton Zeilinger started to use entangled quantum states. Among other things, his research group has demonstrated a phenomenon called quantum teleportation [entanglement swapping], which makes it possible to move a quantum state from one particle to one at a distance." Please see my answer below for specific citations of Zeilinger's Nobel-worthy work, completely contradicting your comment.

@Dr. Chinese Yes, we can add enough delay to force time order, but the general scenario does not have time order and that is why there can be absolutely no physical interaction between such events. My comment explains WHY the order doesn't matter, which is not modified by adding some irrelevant extra delay. The causality structure of the universe is enforced by the underlying classical metric spacetime. Quantum mechanics sits on top of that structure, not underneath it.

@DrChinese You can't move an arbitrary quantum state in an instance. You can make two entangled states that are otherwise unknown before at least one has been measured. All of this is absolutely trivial. Some people want to see a mystery where there is none. At least I don't consider the random mailing of left and right shoes as important physics.

@FlatterMann "You can't move an arbitrary quantum state in an instance." Wrong, you can. Discovered in 1993, "a phenomena called quantum teleportation [which is the foundation of entanglement swapping] makes it possible to move a quantum state from one particle to one at a distance [i.e. nonlocally]". That last quote from the Nobel committee, on awarding the 2022 Nobel to Zeilinger. Let's not continue discussing in comments, as the question has now been answered. You should catch up on modern entanglement theory/experiment, from Peres on. If you have questions, PSE is the right place to ask.

@DrChinese Quantum teleportation doesn't move a known state at an instance. If it did, then it would violate special relativity and we would all have an ansible built into our cell phones by now. The point is not that entanglement in its various forms doesn't exist. The important part is that it does not make quantum mechanics non-local. There simply is, to the best of our knowledge, no non-local physics.

@DrChinese The paper may be Nobel worthy but it is conjecture based on oversimplified QM interpretations from the 1930s ... yes if you use this old interpretations teleportation is conjecturable but the experimental results can be explained in more modern terms ... see wikipedia.

@FlatterMann: "Quantum teleportation doesn't move a known state at an instance" two clarifications: 1) quantum teleportation is not matter teleportation as in Star Trek. It teleports the state of matter, which does not violate special relativity. 2) It does not move the state. It reproduces it while the original is destroyed.

@flippiefanus That's why I said that it does not move a known state. Let's say we could prepare a hydrogen atom into either an s- or a p-state. The difference is, of course, the quantum of energy of the s-p transition. If we could then replicate or at least move this state to a second hydrogen atom instantly, that would mean that that quantum of energy would move instantly. This is the concrete process that would violate relativity and this can, for all we know, not happen.

@FlatterMann, true, but that is not what quantum teleportation means.

@flippiefanus It does once we bring it down to the level of actual physics. What gets people confused in quantum mechanics is that "state" seems to be an abstract. Nothing could be further from the truth. A hydrogen in a p-state has A LOT more energy than a hydrogen in an s-state. Some people are actually welding with that, even though the atomic hydrogen torch "only" uses the dissociation energy of an H2 to 2H, which equals like 4000K. The actual sp transition is around 10eV, if I remember correctly, so that would be equivalent to 120,000K if I am not mistaken.

@FlatterMann, the fact that some people have a misconception about what a quantum state is does not have anything to do with what quantum teleportation does. Quantum teleportation is actual physics because it has been performed many times in physical experiments. People that work in that field generally have a very good understanding of what a quantum state is. This discussion does not seems to lead anywhere useful.

@flippiefanus The simple fact is that IF quantum teleportation could instantly transfer information, then it would have to instantly transfer energy. That can not happen in a relativistic universe. We are dealing with the equivalent of perpetual motion here. No matter how we formulate the laws of thermodynamics in detail, there can be no perpetual motion machines. In the exact same sense quantum mechanics can not transport information/energy instantly across spacetime. That's why understanding quantum state change as a consequence of energy flow is absolutely required for a healthy ontology.

@FlatterMann please first read up on what quantum teleportation is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation). You would not be making these comments if you understood the process.

@flippiefanus The process does not transport energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge instantaneously. If it did, you would have built yourself an ansible.

This has been experimentally verified in hundreds of experiments.  Here are examples of well-known implementations by Zeilinger teams:
A. Experimental delayed-choice entanglement swapping (2012)
B. Experimental Nonlocality Proof of Quantum Teleportation and Entanglement Swapping (2002)
C. High-fidelity entanglement swapping with fully independent sources (2009)
There are several important points to make:
i) The order of execution ("after" or "before") of the Eve (or Victor) measurement has no observable affect on the outcomes.  (Reference frame is of no consequence since order does not matter.)  This is clearly demonstrated in the experimental implementations.
ii) In the A. reference, there is a common source for all 4 photons.  But in the C. reference, the photons sources are fully independent and spatially separated.
iii) In fact, in that setup: the 1 & 4 photons which are tested by the CHSH inequality never exist in a common light cone and have no mutual interaction at all (assuming you consider c a hard and fast limit for an influence).
So your concept of "after" being the issue cannot be correct, since nothing changes regardless of how you define "after".  And everything presented in the experiments fully conforms to standard QM and the presentation of Peres.  Of course, Peres' paper is a primary reference for all of these.
So let's look at Peres' [6] which you mention.  Yes, this is the state prior to a measurement by Eve.  The decision to analyze everything from the perspective of what Eve's outcome is essentially arbitrary.  That's because there is no difference due to the order of measurements.  You could also arrange things so Eve's measurement occurs between Alice and Bob's, and again nothing changes.  So the choice of looking at Eve's result first is a convenience.  So why choose that?  Once you learn Eve's Bell state (let's call those photons 2 & 3): photons 1 & 4 will violate the CHSH inequality.  But as indicated in reference A., they will also be perfectly correlated in the EPR sense.
For the entanglement of Alice and Bob's photons (1 & 4) to be created, the photons Eve observes (2 & 3) must be indistinguishable.  That means they must arrive together within a narrow time window.  If one or the other of photon 2 or 3 are intentionally delayed by Eve, there will be no entanglement.  This is demonstrated by obtaining Entangled State statistics or Separable (Product) State statistics as presented in reference A. figure 3 according to whether they are made distinguishable.
Also please note: while Peres' paper mentions (correctly) that there are 4 possible Bell states that may be observed, only 2 of the 4 can be experimentally identified using current technology. This limitation does not alter the conclusions.

And just to be clear about the Delayed Choice implementations in general: I would recommend the following roundup of Delayed Choice theory and experiment, Zeilinger is a co-author on this too.
D. Delayed-choice gedanken experiments and their realizations (2014)

Thank you, I'll follow up with some of this

@Mat Also read the wiki article on the dcqe experiment. The research is interesting but interpretations can/are misleading. Many papers are written to get funding/attention/interest even when they know full well that what they are proposing maybe or is likely incorrect.

This answer sweeps the biggest issues here under the rug.  It’s true that the outcomes turn out to be the same regardless of measurement order.  But our standard quantum models of what is happening in the middle are wildly different depending on the measurement order.  And you can’t look to relativity to freely change the order, since it’s not a mere Lorentz Transformation we’re talking about; it can literally be changing the sequence of timelike-separated events.

I do think that it’s reasonable to take the position that the order doesn’t matter, not only because the outcomes are identical, but also because of the path integral viewpoint of the same experiments ( https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02945).  But, if you apply this equivalence to the standard QM interpretations of these experiments, this pushes you into the camp of retrocausal interpretations (see both the above paper and https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.05370 , particularly the Appendix).  That may be the right move, but it’s not standard QM.

To summarize:  if the measurement order in these experiments really doesn’t matter, then the mathematics of conventional QM is so disconnected from reality that it is essentially incorrect.  Conversely, if QM is essentially correct, then somehow the measurement order must greatly matter at some hidden level – maybe via some hidden reference frame – but that second paper in the previous comment points out more problems which would result from even that viewpoint.

I think I understand a bit better now and believe the language about the order not mattering should be weakened a bit--order doesn't matter for the experiments & statistics discussed.  However, once e.g. Alice/Bob measure, the state changes from pure Eqn 6 to a mixed state (containing analogous 4 terms).  So the results discussed here end up the same (I think), but a more complicated experiment could expose interference if & only if Alice/Bob did NOT measure.  Right?

@Mat Interference in the DSE and many experiments is a property of of the EM field in the apparatus you choose to observe it. A photon from the sun about to enter Thomas Younge’s experiment will only be allowed certain pathways ( bright areas) not allowed in the dark bands.

@KenWharton I upvoted one of your comments, as I follow the papers you & Price (& others) write. This isn't the spot to discuss those properly, but I always enjoy your analysis/commentary. I like your discussion of path integrals, good point. I disagree with your application of "Collider Bias" to the swapping arena, but agree about figuring out what's going on in the "middle". But isn't that the big question we all have with interpretations? Clearly, DCES (Peres-like) experiments are pushing the limits of our understanding, but without taking us much closer to a single reasonable answer.

@Mat There is no known change due to what Alice/Bob do or don't do, nor change in order. This has been explored extensively in every imaginable experimental and theoretical permutation, including looking for interference effects. Ken's point is that it is still possible that order makes a difference, but not in the statistical predictions. Perhaps "collapse" (whatever that is) is a real physical effect. Like a flipped coin depends on a variety of variables: The quantum outcomes themselves change with order changes, but the quantum statistics remain the same.

You write:

Alice and Bob independently prepare the Bell state $\Psi^-$. They measure one qubit and send the other qubit to Eve. The joint state of the system is written in terms of the qubit-pair Eve now has on the right side of equation 6 (page 3).

In the paper in the paragraph before equation 6 the authors write (emphasis mine):

In the proposed experiment, two distant observers, conventionally called Alice and Bob, independently prepare two sets of singlets, whose states are denoted as $\Psi^-_A$ and $\Psi^-_B$. Alice and Bob keep one particle of each singlet and send the other particle to a third observer, Eve, who also arranges them in pairs (one from Alice and one from Bob). The three observers keep records specifying to which pair each particle belongs.

Alice and Bob each keep one particle and send the other to Eve. They do not measure it at that stage. The premise of your question contradicts the text of the paper you are citing. I advise you to learn to read more carefully.
Update. I will deal with the rest of the question:

It seems to me this is bogus: given that Alice & Bob measured and collapsed the state, how can we subsequently use the state before those measurements?
While writing this I realized the main jist of the paper may still work if we assume Alice/Bob measured "after" Eve, so Eve did measure on the state in equation 6. Maybe this is just a minor problem with how the concept was introduced? Or maybe I'm missing something bigger, "after" may be problematic here?

Alice and Bob may be spacelike separated from Eve at the time of their respective measurements in which case there is no fact of the matter about the order of the measurements. The results don't depend on the order of the measurements. It is helpful for calculations to have an order in which you're going to apply operations so you might as well apply the Alice and Bob operations first since it makes no difference to the result.
Another thing to note is that the word "collapse" doesn't appear anywhere in the paper: measurements are described by POVMs. Nothing about the results depends on collapse.
Collapse has a number of problems as a way of describing measurement. It doesn't describe repeated, continuous or unsharp measurements all of which appear in measurement theory and so it isn't compatible with how calculations are done in practice:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
In many discussions there is no explicit equation of motion for collapse. which makes those discussions vague and difficult to test in detail. Theories that do have collapse built in explicitly don't currently explain the results of experiments on relativistic quantum systems, which are the vast bulk of real experiments:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
In quantum theory without collapse when information is copied out of a system, such as a measurement instrument or record in a computer or lab notebook, quantum interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Decoherence explains why you don't diffract when you walk through a doorway without invoking collapse.
Bell correlations and other entanglement experiments such as the one above can be explained by decoherent systems carrying quantum information that can't be accessed by measurements on those systems alone: locally inaccessible information. The expectation values of the observables of the measurement result don't depend on the quantum information they contain so that information is shielded from decoherence. That information can only be accessed by comparing measurement results from different systems. The relevant correlations are created when the comparison takes place not at the time of the initial measurement:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

Both quotes describe the same methodology, they do not contradict at all. If Peres' paper's description is not clear enough to you or anyone else:  Alice and Bob each measure and/or keep one particle of each singlet. They send the other one on to Eve (or Victor or Bob depending on nomenclature).  Obviously, they don't keep it and not measure it. Any of the experimental implementations of Peres' idea make all of this clear. As is common with important and novel papers such as that of Peres, it is intended for consumption by other experts in the field.

Alanf, the paper and the entire analysis are around Alice and Bob measuring their qubits, and Eve measuring "at a later time."

@DrChinese Your suggestion isn't consistent with the text. The first paragraph of Section 2 "Alice and Bob now measure the values of spin components (along arbitrary directions) of the particles that they kept." This is inconsistent with keep meaning measure since they wouldn't have to state that they are now measuring after sending if keeping already implied measurement.

@Mat Keeping isn't the same as measuring so even if one thinks that measurement causes collapse the state (6) is correct. I will answer the rest of your question but equation 6 is correct.

@Mat I have expanded my answer to deal with your problem.

alanf, in section 2 you'll find "Alice measures spin components ..." and "Bob measures ..."
